# Improve GPS frequency and accuracy

Tags: android, gps

I am exploring the possibilities of using the GPS for VR gaming. Both frequency and accuracy are very low with my current test build.

In manifest I have

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

And I instance location manager like

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
           0, 0, this);
```

I then use the distanceBetween function to get the bearing and distance

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if(lastLocation != null) {          
        Location.distanceBetween(lastLocation.getLatitude(), lastLocation.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), distanceBetween);
        newGpsDataToSend = true;

        if(debug)
            debugListener.debugGPS(distanceBetween);

        releaseSendThread();
    }

    lastLocation = location;        
}
```

The frequency is below 1hz (5-10hz should be possible right?) and the bearing and distance is very jumpy.

Am I doing something wrong in the code? I do not care about battery consumption etc, I jsut want the fastest most reliably data I can get from the phone.

Complete source
https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/FreePIE/blob/VRWalk/Lib/Android/FreePIE%20Android%20IMU/src/com/freepie/android/imu/UdpSenderTask.java#L120

Answer (score 0):

For hight sampling frequencies (counting 1 Hz as high for GPS sampling) you will get GPS readings where the distances between locations is less than the GPS accurracy. Therefore bearing an and distance are jumpy as observed.
To get a better bearing lower the sampling frequency or process the data by filtering or computing an average.

E.g., for a flight logging application I am sampling about every 2 to 5 seconds and I am computing the average of the last 5 altitude readings to compute vertical speed.

Comment: So youre saying its not possible to get better performance? Bummer, Guess I'll have to try kalman filter and accelerometer fusion then :/

Comment: Its a phone, not missile avionics :-)